# Compare 2 JSON objects, remove duplicates

Tags: php, json

I am in need to be abled to compare 2 JSON objects like:

```
$json1 = json_encode('["red", "green", "blue", "white"]');
$json2 = json_encode('["bla", "something", "haha", "blue"]');
```

Now, comparing these 2 objects, the value "blue", is a duplicate, and should be removed from `$json2`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have decoded the JSON into PHP arrays `json_decode($json1, true)` then:

Find the duplicates:

```
$dupes = array_intersect($json1, $json2);
```

Get the difference (without the duplicates):

```
//to remove from $json1
$json1 = array_diff($json1, $dupes);

//to remove from $json2
$json2 = array_diff($json2, $dupes);
```

To just remove from `$json2` it's much easier:

```
$json2 = array_diff($json2, $json1);
```